# Node.js command line with folder name as parameter

Tags: node.js

I was looking at the https://github.com/mars/heroku-cra-node github repo and I noticed that in the `package.json`, there is a script defined as `"start": node server` (server being the name of the folder containing the index.js file).

What exactly does this line do? When we pass a folder name as parameter does node search inside of this folder for the file `index.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node will do a limited search when an exact file can't be found.

In the case of supplying `server` as the "script" argument to `node`:

First `node` will try to open the file named `server`.
If not found then it will look for `server.js`, `server.json` then `server.node` 
If those don't exist and the parameter is a directory, `node` will attempt to open and `server/index.js`, `server/index.json` then `server/index.node`.

First match wins.

```
$ strace -e stat node server
```

```
syscall_332(0xffffff9c, 0x7ffeca72d028, 0, 0xfff, 0x7ffeca72cc10, 0x7ffeca72cd20) = -1 (errno 38)
stat("/server", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/server.js", 0x7ffeca72cc90)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/server.json", 0x7ffeca72cc90)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/server.node", 0x7ffeca72cc90)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/server/index.js", 0x7ffeca72cbe0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/server/index.json", 0x7ffeca72cbe0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/server/index.node", 0x7ffeca72cbe0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/server", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/server.js", 0x7ffeca72cad0)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/server.json", 0x7ffeca72cad0)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/server.node", 0x7ffeca72cad0)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/server/index.js", 0x7ffeca72ca20) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/server/index.json", 0x7ffeca72ca20) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/server/index.node", 0x7ffeca72ca20) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/server'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:893:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:743:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is, yes.

Long answer: `package.json` is recognised by [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/). So long as you have npm installed on your machine you can use it to do many things, such as install NodeJS modules, but you can also use it to run small scripts/commands. These commands must be added under the `scripts` field in `package.json`. To run these commands, you call `npm run <command>`. This feature is for convenience and doesn't have any bearing on package management. That being said, there are hooks available here that get called when publishing a package to [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com) (more on that later).

NodeJS will search for and import `index.js` when importing any folder (CommonJS is probably being used by Node here, but I'm 100% not sure). So in your example, by calling `npm start`, you are calling npm, which is calling `node server` which is running `server/index.js`. You could call anything you wanted here, for example, you could start a shell script by creating a script `"my-script": "my-script.sh"` and then calling it via npm with `npm run my-script`. This is a simple example, but not a very useful one - where npm-scripts comes into it's own is when you have complex commands you need to run regularly.

For example, you could have different commands to run a program with different contexts:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set NODE_ENV=development&& webpack --watch",
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "build-production": "set NODE_ENV=production&& npm run clean && webpack",
    "deploy": "sam deploy"
  }
}
```

- `npm start` for development
- `npm run build-production` to package a production build
- `npm run deploy` to deploy code to server

Note that in the previous paragraph I simply used `npm start`, not `npm run start` as described earlier - there are reserved script names that have extra functionality, see the [npm-scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) page for full details.

Comment: Thank you for your well-detailed answer. My question was more about the command `node server` than on the more general use case of the npm scripts. I wanted to know what does node looks for when the parameters of the node command is actually a folder and not a file directly (for example if my file is called app.js and not index.js, will this be a problem when executing this script ? )

Comment: Just to follow up to my previous comment, I just tried to rename the file to different names and the only case where the command `node server` works is when the filename is actually index.js.

Comment: I think Matt's answer covers that perfectly. In future, I'd suggest cutting out unnecessary information from your question. From the example/phrasing used, I (obviously) got the impression you wanted to know how npm executed scripts.